# SQL Server: Tipo de objeto para funções de tabela no OBJECT_ID()

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Eu gostaria de usar a função **OBJECT_ID** para verificar a existência de uma função que retorne uma tabela e então removê-la caso ela já exista da seguinte forma:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.nome_da_funcao', N'tipo_do_objeto') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.nome_da_funcao
GO
```

Os parâmetros da função **OBJECT_ID** são, respectivamente, o nome do objeto (neste caso, o nome da função) e o tipo atribuído ao objeto na tabela **sys.objects**.

Feita esta introdução, eu gostaria de saber qual é o valor que eu devo passar no segundo parâmetro da função **OBJECT_ID** para checar a existência de uma função que retorne uma tabela.

Eu olhei na [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) os tipos de objetos existentes e encontrei o tipo **IF** que é descrito da seguinte maneira:

> IF = Função SQL com valor de tabela embutida

Porém, não tenho certeza se esse é o tipo correto para o meu uso, pois não tenho certeza ao que se refere uma "função com valor de tabela embutida". Ficaria grato se alguém pudesse esclarecer o que exatamente é esse tipo de objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A documentação dos tipos usandos na tabela "sys.objects" não é muito clara, alguns são simples de entender como:

P = Procedimento armazenado SQL
U = Tabela (definida pelo usuário)

Apesar da tradução, "P"=*stored procedure* e "U"=*user table*, ou uma tabela criada pelo usuário, que é diferente das tabelas de sistema, que já existem no banco de dados.

Já no caso das *functions* ou alguns outros tipos não fica exatamente claro, ou é preciso pesquisar cada um individualmente. Basicamente temos essas:

**FN = Função escalar SQL** -> é uma função que retorna um valor escalar, por exemplo um inteiro, char, etc.
**FS = Função escalar de assembly (CLR)** -> o mesmo do anterior mas que é armazenada num assembly. Pode ser uma função escrita em outra linguagem como `C#` por exemplo e importada para o `SQL Server` através de um *assembly*, ou um "DLL" compilada.
**IF = Função SQL com valor de tabela embutida** -> é uma função que retorna uma tabela, ou mais precisamente o resultado de uma tabela, como um `SELECT`.
**FT = Função avaliada por tabela de assembly (CLR)** -> essa é semelhante à anterior, mas como na "FS", foi definida e importada através de um *assembly*

Para ilustrar melhor, vamos criar uma função *scalar* e uma *table-valued* e ver como isso aparece na tabela de objetos do sistema "sys.objects":

```
create table TabelaTeste (
  id int not null,
  nome varchar(10)
);

create function FuncaoScalar()
returns varchar(10) as
begin
  return (select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103))
end;

create function FuncaoValued()
returns table as
  return (select id, nome from TabelaTeste);
```

O resultado seria, usando o select abaixo seria:

```
SELECT
  object_id
  ,name 
  ,type
  ,type_desc
FROM sys.objects;

+------------+--------------+----+----------------------------------+
| 1013578649 | TabelaTeste  | U  |            USER_TABLE            |
+------------+--------------+----+----------------------------------+
| 1029578706 | FuncaoScalar | FN | SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION              |
| 1045578763 | FuncaoValued | IF | SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION |
+------------+--------------+----+----------------------------------+
```

Logo, como a função [OBJECT_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) é usada para simplificar esse `SELECT` e usa esses mesmos tipos, se quiser obter a função scalar basta passar 'FN' ou 'IF' para a função valued:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('FuncaoScalar','FN');
SELECT OBJECT_ID('FuncaoValued','IF');
```

Pode ver o código acima funcionando aqui: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b7651/2)

Comment: Excelente resposta! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Aliás, duas pessoas deram downvotes nesta pergunta. Você sabe dizer se eu fiz algo de errado na minha pergunta?

Comment: A sua pergunta parece bem melhor que a maioria aqui, não acho que -2 seja o melhor a avaliação, mas eu sugiro descrever melhor a dúvida quanto aos tipos de dados da "sys.objects` ou dos parâmetros da `object_id`, assim ela fica mais focada, por exemplo "o que significa os tipos XXX da tabela sys.objects", ou "o que significam os parâmetros XXX da função object_id", e pode listar os que geram dúvida, como o FN ou IF, ou ainda "o que são funções escalres e de tabela embutida", assim fica bem objetiva a sua pergunta :)